# AKS ingress private static IP

Tags: azure, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

In our current target architecture, we want to use a private AKS cluster with a Firewall in fronting it. The only public entry point to the cluster is the public Firewall IP.

The flow in summary:
Public IP Firewall -> DNAT -> Ingress controller NGINX with private IP

Please dont question the firewall in front of the ingress, it is a strict requirement.

Options

1. Dynamically assign a private IP to the ingress: The downside is that the Firewall DNAT rule may break if the ingress controller is re-created/re-started and is assigned a different private IP.
2. Assign a static private IP to the ingress: The downside is that this is hardcoded in the manifest file and the IP might have been taken by another resource in the AKS subnet (e.g. a node)
3. Assign a static public IP address. Seems the best option to solve 1) and 2) however we would be in favor of using a private IP within the cluster as the ingress IP doesn’t need to be publicly exposed.
4. Use some sort of private DNS FQDN for the ingress, however it seems like the firewall would not be able to resolve that easily and in general that setup looks complex.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating an internal load balancer in AKS and use it as an entry point between the Firewall and ingress controller?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb